# Create Development Certificate iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am having a problem with the generation of the certificates, the Distribution one I did not have any problem, however, with the Development I have not got it. I believe it and when I download it and double click on the Keychain, I get the Expired (Caduco) certificate, the same happens when I create a Provisioning Profiles, I create it based on that certificate and it is immediately invalid.

[image]

When I select Automatically manage signing the error I receive is that the certificate has to be revoked, however, the error is not solved by revoking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your snapshot, The certificate expires only on

```
Sunday, 26 April  2020, 20:43:32 , Standard Time of Chile
```

It means the certificate is not expired now. But still, it is shown as "**The certificate "iPhone Developer: XXXXX" expires**" in red at the bottom. Please check your system time whether it is changed to any other timezone / time.

Comment: Now to work, turn off the mac for a few hours and everything worked ok.